# Android activity and multi-account issue

Tags: android, multi-user

I have an activity that is shown to the user when a message comes from server: when the message comes from an https connection, the application goes to foreground with the new activity and a notification sound is played

It works like a sharm on a standard phone.
On a tablet with 2 different account configured (Account "Foo" with the application installed and account "Bar" without application) there are some trouble.

- If the message comes when user Foo is logged in, the activity starts normally, with notification sound
- If the message comes when user Bar is logged in, the activity does not start, but the notification sound is played.

There is a way to open an application from another account?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the expected behaviour.
if Bar didn't install the app he should not see the Activity of that application.

Comment: There is a way to show an activity in foreground from another user?

Answer (score 0):

try below **android:showOnLockScreen="true"**